# iOS presenting modal and navigation controller based views

Tags: objective-c, ios, navigation

I'm building an application for the iphone that uses both modal views and navigation-controllers. In my case, the initial screen is a table view within a navigation controller, and if the user clicks on the "+" button, they get a new screen that appears in a modal view sliding up from the bottom of the screen that will allow them to add a new record. Within this modal view I want to have a button that will allow them to select from a list of options.

To provide a quick example, take a look at this screenshot from the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Art/ui_navbarpurposes.jpg. If you look at the "Repeat" option in the second view, that's what I want to emulate -- the user will click on the option and a new view (not a action sheet) will load allowing them to select from a list.

Ideally, I would want this new option screen to slide in from the right like a new view was added to the navigation controller stack. However, since add record screen is a modal view, I can't do that, can I? Or would my modal view need to load my add records view embedded within a new navigation controller?

Hopefully I'm explaining this clearly enough. Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Your last thought is the way to go:  you need to add a navigation controller to your modal view, and then when they tap the table view row, you just push your next view onto the navigation stack.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the confirmation.